# Formatting factors to become vectors

Tags: r, correlation, split, factors

I'm working in R and I want to run correlations on different variables relating to one of my factor variables, service.  I really have no idea how to go about this.  I've looked at melting and transposing, but neither of those functions give me the format that I need.  I'm thinking that I need to split the factor vector into individual vectors (corresponding to each level of service), and then somehow get one numeric variable (sumofcases, for example) to become an observation for the newly created service vector.  So one level of service is Hospitalization and another is Case Management.  I would then have one vector called "Hospitalization" and another called "case management," and the observations in each column would be the corresponding values for "sumofcases." Then I can run a correlation between two service vectors.  This, then, would lead to the creation of numerous dataframes (which is fine if it works).

Here's sample data:

```
Year   Region      Service         SumofCases
2010     10     Hospitalization       324
2011      1     Case Management       200
```

And I want it to look like:

```
Year   Region    Hospitalization      Case Management
2010     10        200                    NA
2011      1        NA                     324
```

I thought it might also be possible that there is something inside of the correlation function that would allow me to run a correlation between levels of a factor, but I haven't found anything thus far.

@Thomas, in response to your answer:

I think this is definitely moving in the right direction, but how do I deal with uneven factor levels?

I ran this code:

```
tmp<-MIC$Service levels(tmp) 
levels(tmp)<-c("Ancillary Services", rep("Health Services",2))
cor(as.numeric(tmp),MIC$SumofCases)`
```

and got the following error:

```
Error in levels<-.factor`(*tmp*, value = c("Ancillary Services", "Health Services", : >number of levels differs > cor(as.numeric(tmp),MIC$SumofCases) [1] NA`
```

Output from running `dput(head(MIC))`:

```
dput(head(MIC))

structure(list(FY = structure(c(6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2006", 

"2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011"), class = "factor"), Region = 

structure(c(1L,4L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "10", "2", "3", "4", "5","6", "7", 

"8", "9"), class = "factor"), SumofCases = c(0,1, 1, 2, 11, 14), Service = 

structure(c(17L, 4L, 4L, 4L,4L, 4L), .Label = c("Ancillary Services", "Behavioral 

Treatment","Care Coordination", "Community Living Supports", "Crisis Services", 

"Dental", "ECT", "Employment Services", "Equipment", "Family Services", "Fiscal 

Intermediary Services", "Health Services", "Hospitalization", "Medication",

"Monitoring", "OT/PT/SLT", "Other", "Peer Services", "Prevention", "Residential 

Treatment", "Respite", "Screening & Assessment", "Therapy", "Transportation"), class = 

"factor")), .Names = c("FY", "Region", "SumofCases", "Service"), 

row.names = c(NA,6L), class = "data.frame")
```

After running the following code I get NA for the cor function.

```
tmp<-MIC$Service
levels(tmp)
levels(tmp)<-c("Ancillary Services","Behavioral Treatment","Care Coordination",
           "Community Living Supports","Crisis Services","Dental","ECT","Employment Services",         
           "Equipment","Family Services",             
           "Fiscal Intermediary Services","Health Services",             
           "Hospitalization","Medication",                  
           "Monitoring","OT/PT/SLT",                   
           "Other","Peer Services",               
          "Prevention", "Residential Treatment",       
           "Respite","Screening & Assessment",      
         "Therapy","Transportation")
cor(as.numeric(tmp),MIC$SumofCases)
```

Output:

```
> cor(as.numeric(tmp),MIC$SumofCases)
[1] NA
```

Comment: what language is this again?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: ...can't quite tell what you need without an example, but perhaps you could check out the boot function. http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-bootstrapping.pdf

Comment: you need to encode each level of the factor as its own 0 or 1 variable.  I wrote a function to do this a while ago but it's really inefficient and I'm sure someone here can come up with something better.

Comment: I don't think bootstrapping is appropriate here, it really comes down to a data formatting issue

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is play with the `levels` of your factor to turn it into various dummy variables and then do a point-biserial correlation between that dummy and your other variable(s). I've created some mock data here and run the correlation between a variable `OtherVar` and two different dummy codes of the factor variable:

```
df <- data.frame(Year=sort(rep(2001:2010,10)),
    Region=rep(1:10,10), 
    Service.Description=factor(sample(1:3,100,replace=TRUE), 
       levels=c(1,2,3), 
       labels=c("Hospitalization","Case Management","Other")),
    OtherVar=rnorm(100,0,1))

# one level of factor
tmp <- df$Service.Description
levels(tmp)
levels(tmp) <- c("Hospitalization",rep("Other",2))
cor(as.numeric(tmp),df$OtherVar)

# another level of factor
tmp <- df$Service.Description
levels(tmp)
levels(tmp) <- c("Other","Case Management","Other")
cor(as.numeric(tmp),df$OtherVar)
```

Comment: I think this is definitely moving in the right direction, but how do I deal with uneven factor levels?  I ran this code: 

    `tmp<-MIC$Service
    levels(tmp)
    levels(tmp)<-c("Ancillary Services", rep("Health Services",2))  
    cor(as.numeric(tmp),MIC$SumofCases)`

and got the following error:

    `Error in `levels<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, value = c("Ancillary Services", "Health Services",  : 
  >number of levels differs
> cor(as.numeric(tmp),MIC$SumofCases)
[1] NA`

Comment: Can you put that in your question...it's pretty hard to read as a comment.

Comment: You forgot your closing brackets on your second line of code `levels(tmp) <- c(...)`.

Comment: Also, give us the output of `dput(head(MIC))` so we can see your actual data.

Comment: Your `Service` variable has 24 levels. When you do `levels(tmp) <- ...`, you need to map all of those levels onto the binary categories you want in your resulting `tmp` variable. So instead of just the three levels from my toy example, the right-hand side of that statement should be a character vector of length 24.

Comment: I'm receiving NA for the output, did I edit the code properly? (see above)

Comment: I'm going to offer a completely different suggestion, which is that when you read in your data (presumably using `read.table` or a variant thereof) try setting `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. Then, try just recoding your Service variable using something like `recode` from `library(car)`.